# How to lock a file

Tags: java, multithreading, file, file-io, locking

I have a `write` method that is supposed to safely write data to a file.

```
// The current file I am writing to.
FileOutputStream file = null;
...
// Synchronized version.
private void write(byte[] bytes) {
  if (file != null && file.getChannel() != null) {
    try {
      boolean written = false;
      do {
        try {
          // Lock it!
          FileLock lock = file.getChannel().lock();
          try {
            // Write the bytes.
            file.write(bytes);
            written = true;
          } finally {
            // Release the lock.
            lock.release();
          }

        } catch (OverlappingFileLockException ofle) {
          try {
            // Wait a bit
            Thread.sleep(0);
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new InterruptedIOException("Interrupted waiting for a file lock.");
          }
        }
      } while (!written);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.warn("Failed to lock " + fileName, ex);
    }
  } else {
    log.warn("Failing - " + (file == null ? "file" : "channel") + " is null!!");
  }
}
```

It has worked fine for me for a while now, although I know there are some wrinkles in it.

I have recently changed a project that uses this code to build and run under Java 5 (from Java 6) and now it looks like it is deadlocked awaiting a lock on the file. It is a multithreaded app and it is quite possible for several threads to attempt to write to the same file.

The debugger tells me that the hung threads are waiting for the `FileLock lock = file.getChannel().lock()` call to return.

Some research brought up this interesting little [nugget](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#lock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29) which mentions:

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. **They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.**

So am I doing it wrong? If so what is the right way? If I am doing it right how come I hit a deadlock?

**Added:** Forgot to mention - each thread holds its own copy of this object so there should not be any synchronisation issues within the code. I felt safe to rely on the `FileChannel.lock()` method to ensure writes do not interleave.

**Added too:** I have indeed solved the issue using various `synchronized` mechanisms. I do, however, have outstanding questions:

1. Why is `FileLock lock = file.getChannel().lock();` **not suitable ...**?
2. Why did my issues only appear when switching back to Java-5 when everything worked fine with Java-6?

Comment: Why are you locking the files if you are the only writer? What problem are you trying to solve? I wouldn't use locks as they can cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: I am locking the file to avoid interleaving writes. What problems can file locks cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileLock` is only for interprocess locking, [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) reads:

> "File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine.
>   **They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple
>   threads within the same virtual machine**."

To lock between java threads (same JVM) you need to use some shared lock.  I would suggest within the file writing class to use a synchronized block (which [according](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321349601/explicit-locks/ch13lev1sec4) to [these](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/java_util_concurrent_reentrantlock_vs) [articles](http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Explicit-Locks/Choosing-Between-Synchronized-and-ReentrantLock/) is likely to perform best):

```
final Object lock = new Object();

public void write(...){
  synchronized(lock){
    // do writing
  }
}
```

Another approach is to use a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and then use the proven idiom of

```
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void write(...){
  try {
    lock.lock()
    // do the writing
  } finally {
    // forget this and you're screwed
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: why use a ReentrantLock instead of a simple synchronized block?

Comment: That is what I am beginning to believe:( So I need a lock for each file I write to, even though each file has a channel which can be locked! Do you know what it is about the channel lock that makes it unsuitable?

Comment: @jtahlborn - Synchronized will not help. The issue I use the lock to resolve is interleaving of writes, not concurrent access.

Comment: @jtahlborn synchronized block could work as well, ReentrantLock has a few more features.  Recommend reading the class level javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon sorry that's beyond me, best I can do is refer to the javadoc. I welcome a more informed reader to chime in...

Comment: @cyber-monk - i'm well aware of the features of ReentrantLock, none of which you are taking advantage of here.  in your example, synchronized would achieve the exact same result with less boilerplate.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - my original comment wasn't referring to the overall solution, just the code snippet posted in this answer.

Comment: @jtahlborn as stated, above synchronized block would work as well and after reading this article I think it might even perform better: https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/java_util_concurrent_reentrantlock_vs I'll add that as alternative

Comment: I avoided the problem by protecting the code from multithread access. I still don't understand why a channel.lock is not an effective mechanism for protecting access to a file within the same VM. I would welcome further comments on that.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to implement critical section concept on the actual code using the file, rather than the hashmap. You can either create a synchronized block or separate the file access code into a separate procedure and make that method synchronized.

Essentially, only one thread executes a synchronized block at a time. It gives you the exclusive access you need.

Another way of doing it is, to use a serial thread Executor, depending on your functional requirements.

You may want to look at this thread:
[Howto synchronize file access in a shared folder using Java (OR: ReadWriteLock on network level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320159/howto-synchronize-file-access-in-a-shared-folder-using-java-or-readwritelock-o)

Comment: My apologies - I have added to the question - there should not be any between-threads contention for this method. The lock is used to avoid interleaving writes.

Comment: No need to apologize good sir, but is the problem solved now? Basically, you should not expose the file handle outside a critical section. Define a critical block (method to write) instead of a critical resource (file). Each process calls the synchronized method, gets the connection, appends to the file, closes the connection, releases the block for the next guy.